# Solving for max () in Viterbi algorithm

Tags: markov-chains, dynamic-programming

In simple terms, what is the proper way to solve for max.  I am working with the Viterbi algorithm and am now stuck on how to solve this part of the equation.

pc(G,2)  = 0.3 + max(pc(C,1)+pcc,pn(C,1)+pnc)
         = 0.3 + max(0.2 + 0.5, 0.2 + 0.45)
         = 0.3 + max(0.7. 0.65)
         = 0.3 + ?

Answer (score 0):

$\max\{0.7, 0.65\} = 0.7$. The maximum takes the greatest value of the entries. So your final answer is $0.3 + 0.7 = 1$, of course.